# No implementation found for native method

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to implement a native library into my application. But I keep getting errors no matter what I try.

The functions for the lib is stored java-wise in this class:

```
public class GPUImageNativeLibrary{

    public static native void YUVtoRBGA(byte[] bArr, int i, int i2, int[] iArr);

    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("live_effects");
    } 
}
```

And is being loaded in like this:

```
GPUImageNativeLibrary.YUVtoRBGA(this.f4944a, this.f4945b.width, this.f4945b.height, this.f4946c.mGLRgbBuffer.array());
```

log displays like :

> *07-13 11:21:47.092 3491-3517/com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
>   07-13 11:21:49.590 3491-3491/com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto E/AD: setCenter: Here3
>   07-13 11:21:49.763 3491-3549/com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto E/AD: setCenter: Here3
>   07-13 11:21:50.201 3491-3549/com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto E/art: No implementation found for void com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto.GPUImageNativeLibrary.YUVtoRBGA(byte[], int, int, int[]) (tried Java_com_sigmacode_gifrepeatphoto_GPUImageNativeLibrary_YUVtoRBGA and Java_com_sigmacode_gifrepeatphoto_GPUImageNativeLibrary_YUVtoRBGA___3BII_3I)
>   07-13 11:21:50.208 3491-3549/com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 36151
>                                                                               Process: com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto, PID: 3491
>                                                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto.GPUImageNativeLibrary.YUVtoRBGA(byte[], int, int, int[]) (tried Java_com_sigmacode_gifrepeatphoto_GPUImageNativeLibrary_YUVtoRBGA and Java_com_sigmacode_gifrepeatphoto_GPUImageNativeLibrary_YUVtoRBGA___3BII_3I)
>                                                                                   at com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto.GPUImageNativeLibrary.YUVtoRBGA(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto.km.gpuimage.CRU_InfotechGPUImageRenderer$C16601.run(CRU_InfotechGPUImageRenderer.java:61)
>                                                                                   at com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto.km.gpuimage.CRU_InfotechGPUImageRenderer.runAll(CRU_InfotechGPUImageRenderer.java:276)
>                                                                                   at com.sigmacode.gifrepeatphoto.km.gpuimage.CRU_InfotechGPUImageRenderer.onDrawFrame(CRU_InfotechGPUImageRenderer.java:284)
>                                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1583)
>                                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1286)*

I can't really find any documentation on this.

Comment: `this.f4944a` is this byte array?

Comment: yes it is byte array

Comment: Did you make sure the 'live_effects' so is loaded successfully? If so, where are you calling this method from? (class and package)

Comment: yes @yakobom library is loaded successfully and i'm calling this method from the class "iImageRenderer"

Comment: and do you have access to the native code? is the method signature really 'Java_com_sigmacode_gifrepeatphoto_GPUImageNativeLibrary_YUVtoRBGA'?

Comment: yes it is the same method